# Show data codeigniter from joining table

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a problem.
I want to display Item details, with notes, one Item data has several images that will appear.
I display data in the following way:

I have a model and method like this:

```
class Items_model extends CI_Model
{
public function dataItemsDetail($id)
{
    $this->db->select('
    `items`.`id`, `items`.`item_code`, `items`.`item_name`, `category`.`name` AS
    `category`, `items`.`price_unit`, `items`.`rating`, `images`.`image_name`,
    `items`.`description`
      ');
    $this->db->where('items.id', $id);
    $this->db->join('items', 'items.category_id = category.id', 'right');
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.item_code = items.item_code', 'left');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function imagesItem($id)
{
    $this->db->select('
    `items`.`id`, `items`.`item_name`, `images`.`image_name`');
    $this->db->where('items.id', $id);
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.item_code = items.id');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
```

This my controller:

```
public function itemsDetail($id)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Items';

    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

    $data['itemDetail'] = $this->Items_model->dataItemsDetail($id);
    $data['imagesItem'] = $this->Items_model->imagesItem($id);

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('master/itemDetail', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

And this my view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="item_code" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Item Code</label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $itemDetail['item_code']; ?>" readonly>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="item_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Item Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $itemDetail['item_name']; ?>" readonly>
         </div>
     </div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="images" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Images</label>
       <div class="col-sm-7">
          <?php $i = 1; ?>
          <?php foreach ($imagesItem as $imagesItem) : ?>
              <?= $imagesItem['image_name']; ?>
          <?php $i++; ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div>
 </div>
```

I want to show, item data with one row only, and i want to show multiple image using foreach in view. But that's is, error, the data cannot be show.

This my data from database
[image]

and i want to shwon in this view
[image]

please help me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restructure the item's query a little bit. The first query will return all "single" information you need for your form, the second query is (already) returning the related images:

change this in your controller:

```
public function dataItemsDetail($id)
{
    $this->db->select('items.*, category.name AS category');
    $this->db->where('items.id', $id);
    $this->db->join('items', 'items.category_id = category.id', 'right');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function imagesItem($id)
{
    $this->db->select('items.id, items.item_name, images.image_name');
    $this->db->where('items.id', $id);
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.item_code = items.id');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**note:** the escaping is done by Codeigniter for you, do not use backticks ` in your 
function

**tip:** you can echo out `$this->db->last_query();` and test the generated SQL in your phpMyAdmin

and in your view:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">         
      <?php foreach ($imagesItem as $img) : ?>
          <?= $img['image_name']; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```