# Get value from joined tables, Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to get and display the data from joined tables but I can't get anything in return. I reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464281/show-data-codeigniter-from-joining-table) and it worked on my other function, but when I tried it again on a different function, I can't get any results.

Here's the Model:

```
public function viewReview($id)
{
    $this->db->select('clients.firstname, clients.lastname, packages.title, rate_review.review, rate_review.date_created');
    $this->db->where('rate_review.id', $id);
    $this->db->join('clients', 'clients.id = rate_review.user_id');
    $this->db->join('packages', 'rate_review.package_id = packages.id');
    $this->db->from('rate_review');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function view_review($id)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Rate & Reviews';
    $data['review'] = $this->Admin_model->viewReview($id);

    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_header');
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_topnav');
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_sidebar');
    $this->load->view('../admin/rate_review/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_footer');
}
```

View:

```
    <div class="card-body">
  <p>User:
    <?php echo $review['firstname'].' '. $review['lastname']; ?>
  </p>
  <p>Package:
    <?php echo $review['title']; ?>
  </p>
  <div class="m-2">
    <pre class="border-2"><?php echo $review['review']; ?></pre>
    <br>
    <span class="mt-2"><?php echo $review['date_created']; ?></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I  `var_dump($query)` in `model`, this is what I get [image]

Answer (score 1):

the query seems to be fine except that we do not know if the data really exists in those joined  tables. Are you sure data if there? the  best way to debug is to use profiler so that you preview the real query built  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE), after that take that query and run it on the mysql directly.
place this anywhere in your controller $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE).

Comment: These are the data in my database. [clients](https://ibb.co/4FYgxPM), [packages](https://ibb.co/2qs4gXG), [review](https://ibb.co/8P599cN). But this is what I [get](https://ibb.co/K6hP2Kb)

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure the path is correct and try this query in your model

```
public function viewReview($data) {
        $sql = "SELECT c.firstname as firstname, c.lastname as lastname, p.title as title, r.review as review, r.date_created as date_created FROM rate_review r INNER JOIN clients c ON (c.id = r.user_id) 
 INNER JOIN packages p ON (p.id = r. package_id) WHERE r.id = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
        return (array)$query->row();
}
```

Also please change this line in your controller

```
$data['review'] = $this->Admin_model->viewReview(array($id));
```

Then error log what you get please

```
error_log($data['review']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it gives me error like `Undefined variable: firstname`. Code should work fine but I can't get any data.

Comment: Where does it give that error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to use it like [this](https://codeshare.io/K8dqVN) and it gave me this [error](https://ibb.co/YpZfm6m).

Comment: Not the same viewReview function, please copy my function and use it

Comment: Like [this](https://codeshare.io/K8dqVN)? It gave me this [error](https://ibb.co/Xsj7kyk)

Comment: $sql = "SELECT c.firstname as firstname, c.lastname as lastname, p.title as title, r.review as review, r.date_created as date_created FROM rate_review r INNER JOIN clients c ON (c.id = r.user_id) 
 INNER JOIN packages p ON (p.id = r. package_id) WHERE r.id = ?";

Comment: $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);

Comment: return (array)$query->row();

Comment: You are using sql server, right?

Comment: Also your method definition: public function viewReview($data) {}

Comment: I have updated my answer, please copy my viewReview function

Comment: I tried your updated answer but it gave me this [error](https://ibb.co/ncXjyFh), then I changed the `where r.id = ?` to `where r.id = $data` but it gave me this [error](https://ibb.co/ZcYn2Zw).

Comment: Sql server or mysql?

Comment: I used mysql server

Comment: Please change the following lines

Comment: $sql = "SELECT c.firstname as firstname, c.lastname as lastname, p.title as title, r.review as review, r.date_created as date_created FROM rate_review r INNER JOIN clients c ON (c.id = r.user_id) 
 INNER JOIN packages p ON (p.id = r. package_id) WHERE r.id = :id";

Comment: data['review'] = $this->Admin_model->viewReview(array('id' => $id));

Comment: What am I passing at `where r.id = :id`? I get something like [this](https://ibb.co/Vm9hmt8)

Comment: Forget about updated answer, I have deleted it. Can you please error_log what you get when you implement my original answer? Check my updated answer please.